# SGS2 can't connect to PC for USB file transfer or Debugging mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

I am an Android developer and I have been using my SGS2 for a while and I was accessing the debugging mode without any problem, until I broke my phone's screen. I found a repairer who replaced the screen with another. Since that day I cannot access my S2 neither on Debugging mode, nor on USB File Transfer mode.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

It still charges when connected to PC, but no feedback in my Win 7. I tried with other computers and getting the same things ...

Comment: Sounds like the "repairer" messed up something. Have you checked with him?

Comment: i wanted to be sure before going back to him ! what has he messed up ?

Comment: Guess some "cables". I'm not in hardware, so I cannot be sure: but if it worked before, and all that has changed was some hardware, the culprit is most likely to look for there. Does it still charge when connected? Do you get any feedback on either your PC or the SGS itself when connecting the cable? Have you tried a different cable, and are there any differences then? No charge, no feedback, and no difference would make it pretty sure a messed-up "wiring". Even if charging works, he might have forgotten about the other two (data) pins, or accidentally losened something.

Comment: Thank you @Izzy. I have edited the question to provide some more information for new comers. Please can you explain what you mean by : `he might have forgotten about the other two (data) pins, or accidentally losened something`

Comment: To replace the display, he needed to at least partially dis-assemble the device. I have no idea how it looks from the inside, but he could have accidentally losened some connections, or simply have forgotten to re-attach something. There are definitly some connections he had to replace (to make the touch-screen work). But that's rather an Android unspecific hardware issue. Why not just ask the one person who should be able to tell? We can only guess here.

Comment: yes you are right, thanks for all. I will ask him tomorow, and will come back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Izzy. You were right, he messed something up ? it was difficult to convince him, but he finally knew and repaired it back. Thanks too much.

Comment: Glad the issue solved for you! I've summed up the solution and made it an answer. You might wish to "accept" it, so the question turns up as being "answered and solved" in all lists. Thanks a lot, and enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the issue pretty clearly pointed to a hardware issue (the "repairer" having "messed up" / forgotten to re-attach some "connectors").

As reported back, this guess was correct: Taking the device back to him and have him check, he found the "missing link", repaired it, and the device is fully operational again now.